# Debugging selectors in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, selector

I'm trying to debugg my iphone app, it uses selectors as method-parameter "didFinishSelector:"
When i do step over my method or step into in xcode, it goes over my method forward. Some time later, my method finishes it's work, and .. it has to go into my selector function and i want to see it in Xcode.

How is this signal mechanism is designed ? Something like classic C forks or else multi-threads ? Is it possible to view it during visual debugging ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: I think you need to show us what code you have so far.  I don't really understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //create and authenticate to a google spreadsheet service 
    GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *service = [ self spreadsheetService ];
    NSURL *feedURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: kGDataGoogleSpreadsheetsPrivateFullFeed ];

    //check autentication success ( invoke "googleTicket" method for debug success & error )
    [ service authenticateWithDelegate: self
               didAuthenticateSelector: @selector( googleTicket: authenticatedWithError: ) ];

    //fetch retrieves the feed of spreadsheets entries 
    GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
    ticket = [ service fetchFeedWithURL: feedURL
                               delegate: self
                     didFinishSelector: @selector( spreadsheetsTicket: finishedWithFeed: error: ) ];
```

Here's an example. When i'm debugging, i call step-over, step-over, debugger goes through method [service authenticateWithDelage: didAuthenticateSelector:], it goes directly to [service fetchFeedWithURL: delegate: didFinishSelector:] and after that it goes forward. But i want to see, when this two methods do finish, and i want to see how it goes into my selectors "googleTicket: authenticateWithError" and "spreadsheetsTicket: finishedWithFeed: error:"

Comment: I found only one way to go inside selector code with debugger: i set a breakpoint at a line inside selector method code. Go with debugger through all steps to the end of programm, when "step over" doesnt go anywhere, then i press "continue" and debugger goes to breakpoint inside my selector. It's not a comfortable to debug like this, the proccess is not linear. I want to understand how this objective-c selectors do work, and how it's better to debug them.

Comment: It has nothing to do with selectors. The methods you are calling on the GData service are asynchronous. So they are not linear. Those network connections occur on a different thread and then when completed, your methods are scheduled back on the main thread. So you're doing the right thing by just setting breakpoints in those methods.

Comment: Hm .. so, depending on either method is synchronous or not, debugger is to either go into selector or not ?

Comment: And in case of asynchronous .. situation like this, if i want to call next instructions only after the first "getFeed" finishes (get feed, fetch an entry inside of it, and procceed it), i have to incapsulate next instruction into the selector of "getFeed", no just after ? Or there are some other solutions ?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. But for the second question: Yes, if you want something to be done only after the async operation is completed, then you have to do it after the async operation is completed, which means after you get the completed callback or failed callback.